# DCG encoding facts with lambdas in old Prologs?

Tags: prolog, dcg

Having the rule :

```
nx(X^dog(X)) --> [dog].
```

In old books the query for the above fact is :

```
?- nx(X^R).
```

but now I have to use :

```
?- phrase(nx(X^F),R).
F = dog(X),
R = [dog].
```

because it is encoded as :

```
?- listing(nx).
nx(X^dog(X), [dog|A], A).
```

how was it encoded before that it didn't need to be unpacked by phrase().

Comment: In old books it might be `nx(X^F,R,[]).` There was never any other encoding. What book are you referring to?

Comment: NLP for Prolog Pro and Prolog for NLP analysis

Comment: f.e. the see the n()  : np(Sem) --> d((X^Res)^Sem), n(X^Res).  ... is it because it is inside a rule ?

Comment: Yes, inside a DCG rule you call the other rule without extra arguments and without `phrase`. Only when calling a DCG rule from non-DCG code do you use extra arguments (old style) or `phrase` (new style).

Comment: But where did you see `?- nx(X^R).`?? Not in Pereira & Shieber to say the least.

Comment: I think that Colmerauer's original Marseille Prolog was actually DCGs (or 
"metamorphosis grammars") and then it was generalized/simplified to not have the continuation passing part (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar#History). I've never seen a Prolog that didn't require phrase/3 or phrase/2 (the oldest implementation I've used is Edinburgh's C-Prolog)

Comment: [Prolog 0](http://alain.colmerauer.free.fr/alcol/ArchivesPublications/HommeMachineFr/HoMa.pdf) did not have an explicit grammar formalism. The coding convention for the difference list was first argument and last argument.  And not: but last and last argument, as it is since Pereira's DCGs. [Prolog I](http://prolog-heritage.org/fr/ph12.html) (also known as Marseille Prolog) did have an explicit grammar formalism in at least 1975 - that is prior to DEC10 and DCGs. The Wikipedia entry you cite suggests that it has been only 1978 or so.

Comment: sorry .. I renamed  n() to nx() in my tests ... the snippet from the book is n() .. i.e. treat it  as if they are n()